# How do I find out which application is sending me this Notification Center alert?

Tags: notifications

[image]

It appears every 10 minutes or so, and it's driving me nuts! Nothing appears in my notifications slider (the black translucent drawer from the right screen).

Macbook Pro, 10.11.3 El Cap

For googlability: the text is:
AUTH_NOTIF_TITLE
AUTH_NOTIF_MESSAGE

Options:
Close
CONTINUE

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you can click on the message area in the notification and the associated app will be launched.

FYI, this looks like the app's localization is configured incorrectly or is missing.